# Максимально быстро создать новую таблицу на основе партиции

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Подскажите, как можно максимально быстро создать новую таблицу на основе партиции уже существующей?

Речь идет о большом объеме данных и критичности времени выполнения создания. Может есть какие - то фишки...

Comment: "_создать новую таблицу на основе партиции уже существующей_" - что вы понимаете под этим?

Comment: На основе данных, содержащихся отдельной партиции. То есть insetr into table select from partition

Comment: А чем  `insetr into table select from partition` не устраивает?

Comment: Думал может как-то через перенос партиций или еще как-то быстрее может быть.

Comment: Создайте таблицу со структурой существующей, и `insert /*+append*/ into tabnew select * from tabold partitition (part1) where 1=1`. Помоему так, проверте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версии 12.2 появилась возможность обменяться партициями между таблицами и, таким образом, выделить партицию в отдельную таблицу или наоборот, преобразовать отдельную таблицу в партицию. Простой пример:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE partitioned_table;

ALTER TABLE partitioned_table
EXCHANGE PARTITION partition_name
WITH TABLE new_table
WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

Имеются нюансы, вроде необходимости отключать некоторые ограничения и работы с индексами. Необходимо проштудировать документацию.

Если данные в исходной партиции нужно сохранить, можно сначала выполнить обмен с пустой таблицей, затем создать на её основе клон стандартным `create table as select`, затем выполнить обратный обмен.

Comment: О! Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, просто и быстро.
Правда все индексы, триггеры и тд придётся для неё создавать отдельно.

первичный ключ можно задать при создании.

CREATE TABLE new_table (old_table_id PRIMARY KEY) AS SELECT * FROM old_table where ...